# Is logrotate -f not supposed to be used anymore?

Tags: logrotate

So I wanted to logrotate all my logs today and in particular "named" logs for a debug purpose.  But it seems that it is not possible in today's Debian-based distributions. Even if it seems to work when you use the `-d` option, it doesn't create any new logs.

So I've looked into using logrotate on the fail2ban and bind9 logs.

- For fail2ban, it tells me that `/var/log` is insecure so it refuses to create new logs.
- For bind9, it prints me all the renaming jobs and then finishes by telling me that it can't delete the last logs because it doesn't exist. And indeed, it actually did not rotate the logs.

I've even tried to it under the user `bind` or `syslog` but with the same result.

Nevertheless I can see that it rotates the logs every day.  So is this a new behavior under Ubuntu, Debian, etc.? Or is it because `logrotate -f` is deprecated? Or is it something else?

[EDIT]
Still not working with new version 3.8.7-2ubuntu3.1 under ubuntu distro plus there are a lot of errors of format of double quotes which is clearly an old errors from 2 or 3 years ago already from logrotate and it's happening with dpkg log or term.log and other which are clearly not under user control but under system.

Comment: thanks for the edit:) I was on my phone. I'm going to add some more informations tomorrow.